# predict_model() giving error while using 'sod' (Subspace Outlier Detection) model in pycaret.anomaly

Tags: python, anomaly-detection, pycaret

Getting error while predicting for the test data:

CODE:

```
from pycaret.anomaly import * 
anom_exp = setup(train,session_id = 125,                  
categorical_features=['date', 'hours', 'weekNumber', 'DayName', 'isWeekday'],
numeric_features=['cpu_avg'],                     
ignore_features = ['Timestamp', 'time']) 

sod = create_model('sod',fraction = 0.1) 

sod_test= predict_model(model = sod, data = test)
```

```
ERROR:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3629, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3628 try:
\-\> 3629     return self.\_engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3630 except KeyError as err:

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/\_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas.\_libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/\_libs/index.pyx:163, in pandas.\_libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/\_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas.\_libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/\_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas.\_libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[20\], line 1
\----\> 1 sod_test= predict_model(model = sod, data = test)

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/anomaly/functional.py:941, in predict_model(model, data)
938 if experiment is None:
939     experiment = \_EXPERIMENT_CLASS()
\--\> 941 return experiment.predict_model(estimator=model, data=data)

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/anomaly/oop.py:87, in AnomalyExperiment.predict_model(self, estimator, data, ml_usecase)
48 def predict_model(
49     self, estimator, data: pd.DataFrame, ml_usecase: Optional\[MLUsecase\] = None
50 ) -\> pd.DataFrame:
51     """
52     This function generates anomaly labels on using a trained model.
53
(...)
85
86     """
\---\> 87     return super().predict_model(estimator, data, ml_usecase)

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/unsupervised_experiment.py:1354, in \_UnsupervisedExperiment.predict_model(self, estimator, data, ml_usecase)
1351 else:
1352     raise TypeError("Model doesn't support predict parameter.")
\-\> 1354 pred = estimator.predict(data_transformed)
1355 if ml_usecase == MLUsecase.CLUSTERING:
1356     data_transformed\["Cluster"\] = \[f"Cluster {i}" for i in pred\]

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyod/models/base.py:165, in BaseDetector.predict(self, X, return_confidence)
144 """Predict if a particular sample is an outlier or not.
145
146 Parameters
(...)
161     Only if return_confidence is set to True.
162 """
164 check_is_fitted(self, \['decision_scores\_', 'threshold\_', 'labels\_'\])
\--\> 165 pred_score = self.decision_function(X)
166 prediction = (pred_score \> self.threshold\_).astype('int').ravel()
168 if return_confidence:

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyod/models/sod.py:157, in SOD.decision_function(self, X)
140 def decision_function(self, X):
141     """Predict raw anomaly score of X using the fitted detector.
142     The anomaly score of an input sample is computed based on different
143     detector algorithms. For consistency, outliers are assigned with
(...)
155         The anomaly score of the input samples.
156     """
\--\> 157     return self.\_sod(X)

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyod/models/sod.py:187, in SOD.\_sod(self, X)
185 anomaly_scores = np.zeros(shape=(X.shape\[0\],))
186 for i in range(X.shape\[0\]):
\--\> 187     obs = X\[i\]
188     ref = X\[ref_inds\[i,\],\]
189     means = np.mean(ref, axis=0)  # mean of each column

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
3503 if self.columns.nlevels \> 1:
3504     return self.\_getitem_multilevel(key)
\-\> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
3506 if is_integer(indexer):
3507     indexer = \[indexer\]

File \~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3631, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3629     return self.\_engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3630 except KeyError as err:
\-\> 3631     raise KeyError(key) from err
3632 except TypeError:
3633     # If we have a listlike key, \_check_indexing_error will raise
3634     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
3635     #  the TypeError.
3636     self.\_check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

I looked at the source code and I think I know where the problem is, but editing that did not predict anomalies correctly.

source code: [https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyod/models/sod.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

There is a decision_function which is defined as:

```
def decision_function(self, X):    
return self._sod(X)
```

What I think is the problem: Dataframe X should be changed to array type using check_array(X) before sending it to _sod function

Comment: How does "train" and "test" look like?

Comment: Hi Jon. here's how the dataframe looks like : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJgTcwSxDEL0tLOoxqXThk7p6iojdr29/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 'date', 'hours', 'weekNumber', 'DayName', 'isWeekday', 'time' columns are string type and 'cpu_avg' is float type. 'timestamp' is datetime64[ns]

Comment: Try data=test.values

Comment: it gives error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['cpu_avg', 'date', 'hours', 'DayName', 'isWeekday', 'weekNumber'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Also, data parameter in predict_model function takes a dataframe as input, so isn't passing test.values wrong

Comment: I see. If you believe this to be a bug in pycaret, then you should file it on their issue tracker.